# Binding DropShadowTextBlock into a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I'm trying to bind a DropShadowTextBlock (Like a TextBlock) But it is not possible because it is inside a DataTemplate, so it stays outside the form's tree.
I tried some ways I found here in the forum but no situation fit with mine.
Here's my XAML:

```
 <Blacklight_Controls:DragDockPanel Background="White" x:Name="panel4" Header="Exams" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Maximized="Panel4Maximized" Restored="Panel4Restored" Minimized="Panel4Minimized" Margin="7">
                <Blacklight_Controls:DragDockPanel.HeaderTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Blacklight_Controls:DropShadowTextBlock
                              Text="{Binding TituloModelo}"
                              FontFamily="Verdana"
                              FontSize="11"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Margin="1"
                              TabIndex="1000"  
                              DropShadowDistance="0"
                              DropShadowAngle="45"
                              Foreground="Black">
                            </Blacklight_Controls:DropShadowTextBlock>

                            <Image Grid.Column="2" 
                               code/>
                            <Image Grid.Column="3" 
                              code"/>
                            <Image Grid.Column="4" 
                              code"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Blacklight_Controls:DragDockPanel.HeaderTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="name0" />                        
                    <localControls:LastExam x:Name="nameLastExam"/>
                    <Grid x:Name="name1" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Grid x:Name="name2" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Grid x:Name="name3" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </Grid>
            </Blacklight_Controls:DragDockPanel>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "trying to bind a DropShadowTextBlock".

Comment: The property "Text" of my DropShadow TextBlock will be filled dynamically, depending the rules established in my code behind, then, i need bind this property to can be manipulated in my xaml.cs file

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you want to bind the `Text` property to a dependency property defined in your code-behind (inside the *.xaml.cs file)?

Comment: Yes, normally i simply can do it by acessing the property "Name" of the element. Example: <Blacklight_Controls:DropShadowTextBlock
                             x:Name="NameOfTheElement"
                            </Blacklight_Controls:DropShadowTextBlock> But  in this case, i can't because  my DropShadowTextBlock is inside an DataTemplate

Comment: Text="{Binding Path=TituloModelo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"

Comment: I found a solution. What I needed to do was bind my DragDockPanel and in children set the property that want to edit. Like this:

Comment: In DragDockPanel definitions: <Blacklight_Controls:DragDockPanel Background="White" x:Name="panel4" Header="{Binding TituloModelo}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Maximized="Panel4Maximized" Restored="Panel4Restored" Minimized="Panel4Minimized" Margin="7">

Comment: in text property: Text="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Blacklight_Controls:DragDockPanel}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"